# Having trouble generating my print statement n times and having my if statement work in python

Tags: python, for-loop

```
def game(n):
    #teaches children how to add single digit numbers
    import random
    firstNum=random.randrange(0,10) #1st random number
    secondNum=random.randrange(0,10)#2nd random number
    equation=(firstNum + secondNum)
    print(firstNum, '+', secondNum, '=')
    answer=input('Enter answer: ')
    for i in range(n):
            if equation == answer:
                    print('Correct')
            else:
                    print('Incorrect')
```

Output:

```
>>> game(3)
7 + 2 =
Enter answer: 9
Incorrect
Incorrect
Incorrect
```

Comment: You may wish to consider using `random.randint(0, 9)` instead as that includes the upper bound as well

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing an integer with a string. Convert the input value:

```
if equation == int(answer):
```

Comment: In this case, he is using `input` so that is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(...))` Coversion to an int is done by `eval...`

Comment: @thewolf: No, in Python 3 `input()` replaced `raw_input()`.

Comment: Agreed, but this is marked Python -- not Python 3. Regardless, his described issue is because of the lines of code not included in the loop, no? With the print function, could be either Py 2.7 or Py 3...

Comment: @thewolf: It's probably 3.x. In 2.x, unless you use a `__future__` statement (which a novice is not doing), `print(firstNum, '+', secondNum, '=')` would not generate `7 + 2 =`, but `(7, '+', 2, '=')`.

Comment: @abarnert: Not recently. In Python 2.6 and 2.7, the `__future__` statement is no longer required. You can use either [print function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) OR [print statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt)  In what's new [HERE is the link](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#changes-already-present-in-python-2-6) saying that `__future__` is no longer required...

Comment: @thewolf: You *definitely* need the `from __future__ import print_function` statement in 2.6 and 2.7 to get the proper behaviour. Otherwise you are printing a tuple instead.

Comment: @thewolf: No, try `print(1, 2, 3)`. That is *not* a tuple. `print('is this a tuple?',)` would be a tuple (note the comma!).

Comment: @thewolf: You've misread what you linked to. That's the "What's New in Python 3.0", which says that in 3.0 the `__future__` statement is no longer necessary. But without even trying to figure out what the docs mean, just try the exact statement that I showed in my comment, and you will get the exact output in my comment.

Comment: @thewolf: Also, parentheses don't make a `tuple`; commas make a `tuple`. That's why your example is not a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

and you need to put this stuff

```
firstNum=random.randrange(0,10) #1st random number
secondNum=random.randrange(0,10)#2nd random number
equation=(firstNum + secondNum)
print(firstNum, '+', secondNum, '=')
answer=input('Enter answer: ')
```

into the `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

Move the `for` up:

```
def game(n):
    #teaches children how to add single digit numbers
    import random
    for i in range(n):
        firstNum=random.randrange(0,10) #1st random number
        secondNum=random.randrange(0,10)#2nd random number
        equation=(firstNum + secondNum)
        print(firstNum, '+', secondNum, '=')
        answer=input('Enter answer: ')

        if equation == answer:
            print('Correct')
        else:
            print('Incorrect')
```

Also (if you are not on Python 3) you may wish to consider replacing:

```
input('Enter answer: ')
```

with

```
int(raw_input('Enter answer: '))
```

Because:

```
input(...)
    input([prompt]) -> value

    Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

Since [eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) will potentially execute random bits of Python code. You just don't know what those kids will type these days... :-)

If you ARE on Python 3, you need `int(input('Enter answer: '))` in addition to changing the loop...

Comment: +1 for the `input`—and if he _is_ on Python 3, he probably wants `int(input('Enter answer: '))`, because otherwise it will treat everything as incorrect—the string `'1'` and the number `1` are not equal.